# Crystal Reports - Formula Workshop

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report which groups products based on order number.

I have created a formula which displays the text 'Partially Completed' or 'Fully Completed' based on whether a field on each product called 'Difference' equals 0 or not. If 'Difference' is 0 then 'Fully Completed' is displayed and vice-versa.

What I need to do is to display the corresponding message for the overall order number (i.e. if any of the products for an order have a difference != 0 then display 'Partially Completed'. If all the products have a difference == 0 for an order then display 'Fully Completed'.

This is the code I have attempted so far:

```
StringVar ouputText;

if {AD_999_SB_Fulfillment__Summary.FulfillmentPicking.Difference} = 0 then
    ouputText := 'Full'
else
    ouputText := 'Partial';

ouputText;
```

I assume I need some kind of for-loop to loop through all of the products for an order and check to see if any of the orders have a difference != 0 and then update the message based on if all the products have a difference == 0 or one of the products breaks the condition by having a difference != 0.

Comment: Is there any reason that you aren't using an aggregate?  Such as Sum() or Max().  Then you don't have to loop through all of the rows, just do a summary for that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping is a lenghty process instead you group your report according to the "Order" then place the product in detail part. This will automatically loop entire products in a Order.

1. Create formula with name reset and place it in group header. Code is below.

   Shared stringVar array y;

   ```
   y:=" ";

   join(y);
   ```
2. Create a formula and place it in detail section. This will take the result and store it in array for future use. Use below code.

StringVar ouputText;

Shared stringVar array y;

if {AD_999_SB_Fulfillment__Summary.FulfillmentPicking.Difference} = 0 then
        y:= y+'Full'
    else
        y:= y+'Partial';

```
if {AD_999_SB_Fulfillment__Summary.FulfillmentPicking.Difference} = 0 then
    ouputText := 'Full'
else
    ouputText := 'Partial';

ouputText;
```

1. In group footer create another formula to display whether result is full or partial for order.

   Shared stringVar array y;

   if "Partial" in y
   Then "partial"
   else "Full";

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer this works great. Is it possible to get the result to display in the group header as opposed to the group footer?

Comment: I am afraid it may not work as expected if placed in Group header. If group header is obstructing your design supress it.